# Xamarin iOS TableView not showing up

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am making an app for iOS using Xamarin I had some trouble with UITableViews and found this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data

I created a new project and followed what they did, but it doesn't work for me. I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Could someone take a look and see why the TableView doesn't show up?

BasicViewController:

```
public class BasicTableViewController : UIViewController
{
    private UIView view;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var table = new UITableView(View.Bounds);
        table.Source = new BasicTableSource("aaaaaaaaa", "bbbbb", "cccccccc", "ddddddddddddd", "eeeee");
        Add(table);
    }

    public override void LoadView()
    {
        view = new UIView()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
        };

        View = view;
    }
}
```

BasicTableViewSource:

```
public class BasicTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    private readonly string[] items;

    public BasicTableSource(params string[] items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell");
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, "cell");

        cell.TextLabel.Text = items[indexPath.Row];

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return items.Length;
    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        Window.RootViewController = new BasicTableViewController();

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

What the simulator looks like when running this project:
[What the simulator looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJmvo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause:**

When you override the method `LoadView`.It seems that you forgot to set the `Frame` of `view`.So the size of view will with Height as 0 and Width as 0.

**Solution:**

Set the frame of view as the size of screen.

```
public override void LoadView()
{
    view = new UIView()
    {
        Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds,
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
    };

    View = view;
}
```

Comment: This works, but is it the correct way to do it? Other examples I have seen of overriding LoadView does not have to set the size of the view. What if this controller is a child controller of a container controller? How should size be set then? Or is this a special case because BasicTableViewController is the RootViewController?

Comment: It is necessary to set the size of the view.

Comment: Actually ,I do not suggest you override the method.If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad method. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview?language=occ